# Generate password reset URL

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to send Keycloak user reset password email from my web app without using Keycloak SMTP configuration. For that I am trying to generate the reset password link but I am not sure how to generate the code in URL. Are there any API call to generate action code or full reset password URL ? Keycloak generate something like below. I need to generate same. That's the objective.

https://server.com/auth/realms/xxx/login-actions/action-token?key=ffdfdfdfd

Comment: hello, did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API directly exposed in Keycloak.

Keycloak provides action tokens that permits its bearer to perform some actions, e.g. to reset a password or validate e-mail address.

Perhaps you could have a look at the action tokens SPI:
http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/action-token-spi.html

This way you can handle your use case.

Answer (score 0):

you should override one SPI and here is solution.
Create your custom ResetCredentialEmailSender class which will replace default step in reset-credentials-flow, and implement these interfaces:

```
public class ResetCredentialEmailSender implements Authenticator, AuthenticatorFactory 
    @Override
  public String getId() {
    return "reset-credential-email-sender";
  }
```

Then copy logic from org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.resetcred.ResetCredentialEmail

Override this method with your own logic:

```
@Override
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context)
```

Then in reset-credentials-flow just replace with your prividerId you created:
[image]